Use of dative with быть
In this poem by Marina Tsvetaeva we have:

Не упразднившему — тренья

I don't understand the construction of this sentence. I believe that тренья is the subject. Is the meaning the same as Тренья не упразднившие?

Here's a more extended excerpt from the poem:

Народоправству, свалившему трон,
Не упразднившему — тренья:
Не поручать палачам похорон
Жертв, цензорам — погребенья
Пушкиных.

First of all, this is not anything close to idiomatic Russian. Its grammar is very weird, choice of words peculiar and punctuation non-standard.
That said, what this sentence seems to convey is something along these lines: "The democracy that has knocked down the throne but hasn't abolished the tensions is not to put executioners in charge of their victims' funerals, or censors of interment of Pushkins".

Народоправство is a calque from "democracy", with a derisive overtone.
I honestly have no idea what the em dash between упразднившему and тренья is supposed to mean.
Трения (literally, "frictions") means "social tensions, discord". The syncopic form тренья is used here to maintain the meter.
Why the word упразднить is being used with трения, I don't know either. Probably some kind of metaphor or something.
The infinitive in conjunction with the dative can be used to convey the imperative (or, rather, jussive) mood, similar to the Italian impersonal imperative, or to English constructs like "Alice to call Bob and report the status of the work", that are used in meeting minutes.


Thank you very much! Now I see: there was no reason to assume that the dash was a form of быть; as a consequence I assumed that тренья was in the nominative, while it was in the accusative. Having fixed these two points the text is clear to me now and, except the weird punctuation with these dashes, to me (probably because I am not a Russian native speaker) I don't see anything weird.

@Bruno: I, a native speaker, spent several minutes myself googling for other possible meanings of тренья that could make the phrase read like народоправству — тренья, similar to землю — крестьянам, заводы — рабочим, мир — народам. It would make much more sense, but, apparently, it isn't the case.

In "землю — крестьянам", why землю and not земля?

@Bruno: it's an ellipsis: землю (отдать) крестьянам. It's actually being used with the nominative as well: земля (принадлежит, должна перейти) крестьянам

There is a full translation of this poem by a Russian at https://lyricstranslate.com/ro/stikhi-k-pushkinu-poems-pushkin.html I say Russian, although I don't know what kind of surname Shambat is. He is Ilya Shambat - is this a Jewish name? He has translated every single line of Tsvetaeva's poetry at https://sites.google.com/site/ibshambat/tsvetayeva-full?authuser=0 and so must be considered an authority on her.
But he is not a native speaker of English, and his translation is difficult to understand. He translates

Народоправству, свалившему трон, Не упразднившему - тренья: Не
поручать палачам похорон Жертв, цензорам - погребенья   Пушкиных.

as

The people's power, having overthrown the throne, Not celebrated -
friction: To executioners not to allow burial Of victims, the burial
of Pushkin   To censors.

I'm not aware of all the possible older meanings of упразднить - can it really mean "celebrate"?
Could it mean "the people's power, which has overthrown the monarchy, but has not done away with absolute power for itself, should face dissent/the executioners should not be allowed to bury the victims/ and the Communist censors should not be allowed to bury the Pushkins (do away with Russia's poets and identity and culture)"? I'm giving a free translation here trying to capture the internal meaning, not translate the words.
Bear in mind, this poem was written in 1931, when Tsvetaeva was living outside of the Soviet Union.

The Russian original is not that easy to understand either. Russian for "celebrate" is праздновать which does share the root with упразднить but other than that, isn't even remotely related to it semantically. How can "friction" come to mean "absolute power", that I don't understand either.

No, friction doesn't mean absolute power. In my suggested translation, трения is "dissent". Absolute power is трон. The Bolsheviks overthrow the throne, but did not liquidate the throne (they overthrew the throne in order to keep the throne's power for themselves). It is only a suggestion, and assumes the object of упразднившему is трон. But my post was only a suggestion. I think that translator of Tsvetaeva's poetry could give a reply on this??

Вся власть -- советам. This pattern could be used here? Трения -- народоправству.

I've just sent an email to Shambat, who lives in Australia. Let's see if I get a reply.

@pompey1969 "Вся власть -- советам. This pattern could be used here? Трения -- народоправству." This suggestion was closer to my first try, that is with тренья in the nominative because I insisted to take the dash "seriously". Quassnoi's suggestion is to consider тренья as an object of упразднившему and then everything makes sense to me (except maybe the dash, which is perhaps just a way to induce a pause In the reading?). I see now the dative Народоправству as a way to say to whom the "imperative" поручать is addressed ("To the popular justice" - if "To" can be used here in English).

Bruno I think Shambat's translation of the entire corpus of Tsvetaeva a useful link. I liked the first poem: He смейтесь вы над юным поколеньем!/
Вы не поймёте никогда,/
Как можно жить одним стремленьем,/
Лишь жаждой воли и добра.../
Вы не поймёте, как пылает/
Отвагой бранной грудь бойца,/
Как свято отрок умирает,/
Девизу верный до конца!/
Так не зовите их домой/
И не мешайте их стремленьям, --/
Ведь каждый из бойцов -- герой!/
Гордитесь юным поколеньем!

It probably means what Quassnoi said - I was confused by Shambat's version and particularly his word "celebrated" - indeed his version seems to be in incorrect English. But reading it again, it seems he has the same meaning as Quassnoi, apart from the word "celebrated". This is very peculiar.

Упразднить is to remove, трения is разногласия, which  can be translated as friction, as well as troubles, misunderstanding. All answers have good ideas.

This verse is a kind of an exorcise against outlaws - the word народоправство hears like arbitrariness of ones who was not blessed to rule by law but only by criminal order. Not so bluntly but in a same sense - Cvetaeva was and opposite to the Bolshevik's rule.
So, the first part is:

Народоправству, свалившему трон,
Не упразднившему — тренья:
Не поручать палачам похорон
Жертв, цензорам — погребенья\
Пушкиных.

If it unwird, looks this way:
Народоправству, свалившему трон, Не упразднившему — тренья:
Не поручать палачам похорон Жертв,
цензорам — погребенья Пушкиных.
By the end: Pushkinyh ~ the artists; then on second line word "поручать" means to entrust to do something. So the dash mean same word - do not let/trust(~entrust) to executors their victims burying.
Упразднить - to cancel/remove, and about first one dash трение ~ friction - it is a physical law, so she said something, that criminals broke the human(monarchy) laws(law of civilians) but they unable to broke the word laws like physics in same moment. They able to fall the throne but thay unable to fall the world, that created by the artists like Pushkin and others.
So i think, at the dash place have to be words physic laws like frictions ~ the resistance of the created word.
So, she said: they can take the throne by force, but thay unable to take the world of ideas and to rule it. A prohibit them to do this, because am a artist like Pushkin.

"So the dash mean same word - do not let/trust(~entrust) to executors their victims burying." Yes, I had no issue with the second dash; in my grammar they give this example: "Я бросила к двери, она - к окну."; I think it is the same case here. The use of the first dash and your explanation ("about first one dash трение ~ friction - it is a physical law") are unclear to me, but I think very interesting your interpretation for трение (you made me realize that it is the word used in physics).

@Bruno usually dash replaces some word or phrase that the reader has to guess out or already knows it from the analogue said before. It can be the same phrase, or synonym or similar metaphor based on text difficult. In general sense dash need to switch view focus to something else. It is like she put a spell that народоправство is an usurpation(forgot this word xD) of the power to right and rule, like Pushkin wrote "самовластительный злодей"  but usurpers unable to take the power belong to God's(Nature's) laws or something like this, it is some kind of mystics

Also i think about this reference from her verse to Pushkin's "Oda of freewill": "Самовластительный Злодей!
Тебя, твой трон я ненавижу,
Твою погибель, смерть детей
С жестокой радостию вижу.
Читают на твоем челе
Печать проклятия народы,
Ты ужас мира, стыд природы,
Упрек ты богу на земле."

And also 'magic of the spelling' is in rhymes: трон - похорон (the throne will be their tomb), тренья - погребенья ( the discord of frictions will bury them) - something like this) so it has several layers of the same understanding.

But this explanation has two flaws. 1) you are assuming тренья means a whole clause of your invention. 2) народоправству is in the dative. Your explanation wouldn't require the dative. Quassnoi's explanation does justify the dative - народоправству не поручать. My explanation is that тренья governs народоправству - dissension towards people power. But I think it might need to be тренья к in that case? It seems clear that no interpretation is perfect. Maybe an opaque line needs to be translated opaquely - which is why Shambat came up with a difficult-to-understand translation?

@pompey1969 i understand your doubts, so, i think, i have to look all the circle of the 7 verses that named "To Pushkin", that are more about Pushkin and this verse is the last, it is most unclear because based on previous ones, probably.
