Why do we have "моей" in "Тебе - моей"?
In this poem by Marina Tsvetaeva we have several times the verse "Тебе - моей.". For instance,

Здесь нету рученьки
Тебе — моей.

I don't understand in which case is моей. Genitive like рученьки? Why?
I know three translations of this poem. One in French. For these two verses, it would be something like

Here - not any hand,
For you mine.

It seems to me that it would rather correspond to

Здесь нету рученьки,
Тебе — моя.

(Тебе — моя рученька)
Another translation in Italian. It would be something like that:

Here there is no help
For you - my dear.

I am surprised by this translation: "моей" -> "my dear" ("mio caro" in Italian) - is it possible to say "моей" to mean "my dear"? Notice also that in the Italian translation the "For you" is the continuation of the previous verse, while in the French translation the second verse is in opposition to the first one (the translator even added a comma to emphasize that the "For you" is not the continuation of the previous verse).
Finally @άνθρωπος let me know a translation in English:

There is no arm here
To you - mine.

which seems similar to the French translation, but without the comma and then we have

There is no gift here
To you - from me.

(like if моей is an adjective of дарственной and the second verse is the continuation is the previous one?).
instead of

There is no gift here,
To you - mine.

Whatever the translation is, I don't understand the "моей".

It means здесь нет тебе моей рученьки "there's no hand of mine for you", rearranged for poetic purposes and generously peppered with em dashes, which Mrs. Tsvetaeva seems to have been very fond of.
The genitive is here because моей defines рученьки, which, in its turn, is the subject of the negated existential clause that in Russian requires the genitive (есть рука / нет руки)
The dative of тебе is the dativus finalis (дательный цели) which is usually translated as "for you".

Thank you very much! Like in my previous question https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/27541/use-of-dative-with-быть it seems to be a good tip, when reading M. Tsvetaeva, to "ignore" most of the dashes in order to understand the grammatical construction. The English translation seems much more faithful than the French and Italian translations (although the translator into French is supposed to be "perfectly bilingual").
